# Mysql Trigger not working, donot know where is the bug

Tags: mysql, database, triggers

```
CREATE TRIGGER pointclosedtrigger AFTER UPDATE ON points
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
 IF NEW.is_open='3'
 THEN
  INSERT into point_history (idpoints,idmembers,action_time,action_type)
  VALUES (OLD.idpoints,NEW.idmembers,NOW(),'2');
 END IF;
END
```

Comment: What isn't working?  Does the `CREATE TRIGGER` statement succeed or fail?  If it fails, with what error message?  If it succeeds, what happens when you try to `UPDATE points ...`?  Do you get an error?  If so, what message?  If not, what behaviour do you observe and how is that contrary to your expectations?  Really, you need to provide more information that this.  -1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to define a delimiter

```
delimiter |
CREATE TRIGGER `pointclosedtrigger` AFTER UPDATE ON `points`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
 IF NEW.is_open='3'
 THEN
  INSERT into point_history (`idpoints`,`idmembers`,`action_time`,`action_type`)
  VALUES (OLD.`idpoints`,NEW.`idmembers`,NOW(),'2');
 END IF;
END
|
delimiter ;
```

If you don't define another delimiter than `;` then your statement will end at the first `;` and it will be incomplete.